How do I simulate and control a 3DOF Inverted Pendulum?
I'm working on a project that involves controlling a 3DOF (latitude, longitude, roll) inverted Pendulum with Thruster (see image for a simplified sketch). The Thrusters will apply impulses onto the pendulum to keep it in the up-right position. Before I even get started on the controls, I would like to be able to simulate the physics of the pendulum and the response of the system due to impulses in Matlab/Simulink. I am unsure how the physics will work though--I have an idea but I'm unsure.

My Idea:
I think that the motion of the entire pendulum can be fully characterized simply by the angular velocity vector $\vec{\omega}$. Here's my reasoning. At each time step, using some trig between my coordinate axes and $\vec{\omega}$, I can find the longitudinal $\phi$ and latitude angles $\theta$--that's 2/3 angular coordinates already. Now, the magnitude of $\vec{\omega}$ gives me it's roll rate, so I could integrate it over some small-time step to find the change in roll angle. And if I have the previous roll angle, then I can simply add together those quantities, and I'll know the new roll angle. Thus, at each time step if I know $\vec{\omega}$, then I'll just do the aforementioned calculations to fully define its position (the 3 angles) in space.
Now, this is all predicated on me knowing the angular velocity vector at each time step. So the question is how do I find that? Well, $\vec{L} = I\vec{\omega}$, where $\vec{L}$ is angular momentum vector, $I$ is the inertia tensor, and $\vec{\omega}$ is the previously mentioned angular velocity vector. Thus, if I know $I$ (which seems simple to calculate) and $\vec{L}$ then I can find $\vec{\omega}$. And $\vec{L}$ can be found by the relationship that $\frac{d{\vec{L}}}{dt} = \sum \vec{M}$, where $\sum \vec{M}$ is the sum of moments about the origin  induced by the thrusters and gravity. I can just do some numerical integration on $\frac{d{\vec{L}}}{dt}$ to find $\vec{L}$ at each time step.
So is this a valid way of simulating the physics? Or am I missing something crucial? And is this way of simulating going to be helpful for the developing the controls? Or will I need actual equations of motions for that. If I do need actual equations of motions, I don't even know where to begin on that. I've only taken a introductory Dynamics course and know no control theory.

To the close voters: [tag:computational-physics] questions on algorithms are not engineering, it is indeed physics. Voting to re-open because this is a good question for this site.

Or will I need actual equations of motions for that Yes, you will need to arrive at equations of motions in order to develop an ODE/PDE to solve for your numerical implementation.

You can indeed model this entire system in angular space.  Now that is a little different from just modeling it using angular momentum.  I'm assuming that by "...fully characterized simply by the angular velocity vector $\vec \omega$, you actually meant to write that it is fully characterized by $(\theta, \phi, \vec\omega)$.  It looks like the rest of your words did indeed support this.  The angles will be important because they affect how gravity affects the pendulum (its input into $\frac {d\vec\omega} {dt}$).  Modeling such a system in angle space is a very common approach for pendulums.

Or will I need actual equations of motions for that.

What you describe are the equations of motion for a pendulum that is constrained in the way you describe.  Your equations of motion do not have to include position, velocity, or acceleration because the constraints placed on the pendulum show that you can compute any one of those using the spherical coordinates for angular position, angular momentum, and angular acceleration (sum of torques).  We say that those three form a complete phase space for your pendulum.  Your simulation is simply doing a numeric integration to compute the result of said equations of motion from some initial conditions.
I highly recommend starting with a 2-d inverted pendulum.  The 2-d inverted pendulum is a very standard introductory controls theory problem, so you will find lots of examples on how to accomplish that goal.  Also, I highly recommend learning control theory before trying to apply controls.  Control theory will help you with understanding how any given control scheme behaves, giving you better certainty in your design.  Without it, the best you will be able to say is "well, it hasn't broken in any of the initial conditions I've tested yet."  With control theory, you can speak to regions of stability that will always converge on your desired outcome.  Instead of saying "well, I think I tuned this well," you can say "I've proven that this tuning is optimal."
Also, control theory will introduce you to Lagrangian mechanics, if you haven't already come across it.  Due to the non-linear effects of gravity as the pendulum moves, it's actually rather difficult to analyze this system using $F=ma$ or $L=I\omega$.  You can simulate it that way without too much trouble, but understanding the controls that way can be a challenge.  Typically when you use $L=I\omega$ in such a case, you make a simplifying assumption that the perturbations from vertical are very small.  This dramatically simplifies the equations.  Such assumptions can be very tricky with bang-bang controls (your words suggest that you are treating the thrusters as a source of impulse, and are not throttlable), as they tend to lead to larger perturbations.  Lagrangian mechanics was invented to deal with curvilinear coordinate systems such as the spherical system you have for $(\theta, \phi)$.
You may also want to start with a simplified model with different controls.  The 2d inverted pendulum is simple enough that, with some controls theory, you can show that a reciprocating saw, tuned to the right frequency, is actually sufficient to keep it upright.  You may also look at permitting variable output thrusters, which would let you use ideal control laws such as those defined using the Hamiltonian (not to be confused with the related Hamiltonian mechanics).  These control laws are well understood enough that they can be used as part of verification of your simulation.  If they do not demonstrate the proper inverted pendulum behaviors, it means your simulation model may not be correct.  Once your simulation is credible, then you can use it to analyze the responses to the model you really want to study.

Is there a text(s) you would recommend for me to learn the controls and Lagrangian Mechanics?

$\def \b {\mathbf}$
$\def \p {\dot}$
$\def \pp {\ddot}$

The Equations of motion
Translation
\begin{align*}
&\text{Position Vector}\\
 &\b P= \left[ \begin {array}{c} r\cos \left( \vartheta  \right) \cos \left(
\varphi  \right) \\r\cos \left( \vartheta  \right)
\sin \left( \varphi  \right) \\r\sin \left(
\vartheta  \right) \end {array} \right]\quad\Rightarrow\quad\text{Velocity}\\
&\b v= \left[ \begin {array}{c} -r \left( \sin \left( \vartheta  \right)
\cos \left( \varphi  \right) \p\vartheta +\cos \left( \vartheta
 \right) \sin \left( \varphi  \right) \p\varphi  \right)
\\-r \left( \sin \left( \vartheta  \right) \sin
 \left( \varphi  \right) \p\vartheta -\cos \left( \vartheta  \right)
\cos \left( \varphi  \right) \p\varphi  \right) \\r
\cos \left( \vartheta  \right) \p\vartheta \end {array} \right]
\end{align*}
Rotation
\begin{align*}
 &\text{Rotation Matrix}\\
 &\b R=\b R_z(\varphi)\,\b R_{y'}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\vartheta\right)\,\b R_{z'}(\psi)\quad\Rightarrow\quad \text{Angular velocity}\\
 &\b\omega=\left[ \begin {array}{c} -\sin \left( \psi \right) \p\vartheta -\cos
 \left( \vartheta  \right) \cos \left( \psi \right) \p\varphi
\\-\cos \left( \psi \right) \p\vartheta +\cos
 \left( \vartheta  \right) \sin \left( \psi \right) \p\varphi
\\\sin \left( \vartheta  \right) \p\varphi +\p\psi
\end {array} \right]
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
 &\text{Kinetic Energy}\\
 &T=\frac{m}{2}\,\b v\,\cdot\,\b v+\frac{1}{2}\b \omega^T\,\b I\,\b \omega\\
 &\text{Potential Energy}\\
 &U=m\,g\,\b P_z+\tau_\vartheta\,\vartheta+\tau_\varphi\,\varphi+\tau_\psi\,\psi\\\\
 &\b I= \left[ \begin {array}{ccc} \theta_{{\vartheta }}&0&0
\\0&\theta_{{\varphi }}&0\\0&0&
\theta_{{\psi}}\end {array} \right]\quad\text{with}\quad \theta_\vartheta=\theta_\varphi\\\\
&\text{where $~\tau_i~$ are external torques }\\\\
&\text{The Lagrangian }\\
&\cal{L}=\rm T-U
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
&\text{The Equations of motion}\\
&\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial \cal L }{\partial \b{\dot{q}}}\right)^T=
-\left(\frac{\partial \cal L }{\partial \b{{q}}}\right)^T\\
&\b q=\left[ \begin {array}{c} \vartheta \\\varphi
\\\psi\end {array} \right]
\quad,\b{\dot{q}}=\left[ \begin {array}{c} \p\vartheta \\\p\varphi
\\\p\psi \end {array} \right]\quad\Rightarrow\\
& \pp\vartheta ={\frac {\tau_{{\vartheta }}}{{r}^{2}m+\theta_{{
\varphi }}}}-{\frac {r\cos \left( \vartheta  \right) mg}{{r}^{2}m+
\theta_{{\varphi }}}}\\
&\pp\varphi ={\frac {\tau_{{\varphi }}}{ \left( \cos \left(
\vartheta  \right)  \right) ^{2} \left( {r}^{2}m+\theta_{{\varphi }}
 \right) }}-{\frac {\sin \left( \vartheta  \right) \tau_{{\psi}}}{
 \left( \cos \left( \vartheta  \right)  \right) ^{2} \left( {r}^{2}m+
\theta_{{\varphi }} \right) }}\\
&\pp\psi =-{\frac {\sin \left( \vartheta  \right) \tau_{{\varphi }
}}{ \left( \cos \left( \vartheta  \right)  \right) ^{2} \left( {r}^{2}
m+\theta_{{\varphi }} \right) }}+{\frac { \left( {r}^{2} \left( \cos
 \left( \vartheta  \right)  \right) ^{2}m- \left( \cos \left(
\vartheta  \right)  \right) ^{2}\theta_{{\psi}}+\theta_{{\psi}}+
 \left( \cos \left( \vartheta  \right)  \right) ^{2}\theta_{{\varphi }
} \right) \tau_{{\psi}}}{\theta_{{\psi}} \left( \cos \left( \vartheta
 \right)  \right) ^{2} \left( {r}^{2}m+\theta_{{\varphi }} \right) }}
\end{align*}
Simulation

To avoid singularity at
$~\vartheta=\pi/2~$ substitute $~\vartheta\mapsto\vartheta+\epsilon~$ where $~\epsilon~$ small number
Put damping at the spherical joint
$~\tau_\varphi=d_\varphi\,\dot\varphi~,
\tau_\vartheta=d_\vartheta\,\dot\vartheta~,
\tau_\psi=d_\psi\,\dot\psi~$
To control the angle $~\vartheta(t)=  \frac\pi2~$ with the external torque
,$\quad\tau_\vartheta\mapsto\tau_\vartheta+ P\,\left(\frac\pi2-\vartheta\right)~$

with the initial conditions
$~\varphi(0)=0~,\dot\varphi(0)=0~,
~\vartheta(0)=\frac\pi2~,\dot\vartheta(0)=0~
~\psi(0)=0~,\dot\psi(0)=0~$
and
$~[m=20,g=10,\theta_{{x}}= 0.4,\theta_{{z}}= 0.2,\epsilon =- 0.001,r=
 0.7,,P=-800,d_\varphi=20,d_\vartheta=20,d_\psi=20]
$
you obtain this result for $~\vartheta(t)~$


My only confusion is about the $\tau$'s. For example, does $\tau_{\psi}$ represent the torque about the roll axis?

Yes this is  the case $~\psi~$ is the roll axis
